# CSS frameworks in Vue.js

Tags: css, sass, webpack, vue.js

I would like to integrate [Bulma](http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/) into my Vue.js project.

I have previously included included the CDN script tag into my `<head>`.

However after that, I followed [these official instructions](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html) for including Sass pre-processor, as Bulma requires it in a Node project.

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev 

<style lang="sass">   
/*write sass here */ 
</style>
```

Now, the script tag in `<head>` is being commented out, and I can't figure out how to load Bulma properly into my application.

I have imported Bulma in my root component style tags as suggested by @BillCriswell below, as follows:

```
<style lang="scss" src="bulma"></style>

<style lang="scss">
  body {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:blue;
  }
</style>
```

And the stylesheet is properly loaded, however if I add another style tag as further suggested, the styles don't load.

How do I load Bulma into my Vue.js project, and what is the recommended approach for integrating a CSS framework into Vue.js?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to do this since [bulba's `main` entry in `package.json`](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/package.json#L7) points to `bulma.sass`.

```
<style lang="sass" src="bulma"></style>
<style>
  /* Your css for this file... */
</style>
```

or you can do

```
<style lang="sass">
  @import "bulma"
  /* Your css for this file... */
</style>
```

There's no need to do `import bulma from 'bulma'` in your `<script>`.

If you can't just use the style tag it would depend on your webpack config. If you're using the `vue-cli` webpack template I believe you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BillCriswell. Indeed it seems to properly import the stylesheet however any SASS I write within those `style` tags does not get loaded.

Comment: Create another style tag under it. You can have as many `<style>` tags as you'd like. Or, you can just have one style tag and `@import "bulma"`.

Comment: `@import "bulma"` crashes the app with `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./bulma`

Comment: Ah, works for me I'm pretty sure. I'm thinking you might want to go here and look at the sass-loader caveats: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html

Comment: Yeah I saw that, not using indents or anything. @BillCriswell. I guess the current issue is separate question. I'll accept

Comment: No problem! Happy to be able to.

Comment: @softcode, I´ve passed through the same issue as yours. The solution is to use `@import "~bulma"`, that worked for me. If you want to customize bulma you should set your variables (http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/customize/) between `@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass'` and `@import '~bulma'`. And I would suggest you to use `lang="sass"` because although it specifies sass by default sass-loader parses SCSS syntax (https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html) Regards.